# Attachment on email sent by php is incorrect

Tags: php, forms, email, email-attachments

i'm using the following code on my php page to send an email with an attachment:

```
    //define the receiver of the email 
$to = 'myemail@domain.com'; 
//define the subject of the email 
$subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
//create a boundary string. It must be unique 
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com"; 
//add boundary string and mime type specification 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['tmp_name'])));
//define the body of the message. 
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

However, i'm having a few problems and doubs, if you people could help me i would appreciate.

First, if i leave the input of the attachment blank i get an error "Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in ..."

I would want the attachment optional, so if i leave blank i wanted to ignore this error, is that possible?

Second, when i sent an email with attachment and download it from email i can't open the file sent. I get a .zip and when try to open get the following message: "archive is in unknown format or damaged".

Do you know what the problem could be?

Thank you!

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you have a problem in `mail()` function, your host does not allow to use `mail()`

Comment: You can open the attachment correctly on your pc after downloading it of the email? Could it be some problem with the extension of the file uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the script works flawless you need to change `attachment.zip` in the name of your uploaded `curriculum_vitae` file, otherwise you will get only `attachment.zip` no matter what file you upload:

so change:

```
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"
```

with

```
Content-Type: application/zip; name="<?php echo $_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name']; ?>"
```

use this to sending attachment if it's not posted

```
$to = 'myemail@domain.com'; 
$subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com"; 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
if(isset($_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name']) && $_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name'] != ''){ $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['tmp_name']))); }
ob_start();
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php if(isset($_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name']) && $_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name'] != ''){ ?>--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/zip; name="<?php echo $_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name']; ?>"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
<?php } ?>
<?php 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai, worked perfectly. Just to finish, is there any away of solvind the problem of my first question? I mean, leave the attachment input blank and get no error?

Comment: i'm having some problems.
where you have 'booking.php'
i should have this
file_get_contents($_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['tmp_name'])));
right?

i still got the message of warning :/

Comment: sorry, that was a file of mine, did some testing and didn't had a file :)

Comment: Perfect Mihai. Thanks a lot for everything!

Comment: Mihai sorry to bother you again. I notice that emails with caracteres like this "à" or "ç" have problems when i'm readin the e-mail. They appear like this: "Ã§Ã£o". My question is, this is a problem of the webmail program i'm using or it has to be with the encoding i'm using in the code that i use to sent the email?

Answer (score 0):

This simple PHP script or e-mail function is able to send a plain text mail message including a single attached file. The file has to be uploaded first or there should be an existing file on your web server. You can use this

**Function :**

```
<?php
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
}
?>
```

**Code:**

```
<?php 
$my_file = "somefile.zip";
$my_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your_path_here/";
$my_name = "Olaf Lederer";
$my_mail = "my@mail.com";
$my_replyto = "my_reply_to@mail.net";
$my_subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
$my_message = "Hallo,\r\ndo you like this script? I hope it will help.\r\n\r\ngr. Olaf";
mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, "recipient@mail.org", $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);
?>
```